# Postfix SSL USING SNI

Tags: mysql, postfix, sni

I What to give assign multiple SSL cert to Multiple Domains

I have manage to do so :

by creating a single wild card SSL cert (e.g mail.example.com , mail.example2.com, etc)

But I Want Each domain to have its own ssl cert.

Like So
smtpd_tls_cert_file = msql:/etc/postfix/pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = mysql:/etc/postfix/key

SQL query is

Select dir From ssl where domain = "$1" limit 1;

Comment: The part that ties each recipient domains to one or more mail server names is the MX record type in DNS. Because the many-to-many relationship is already defined there, one mail server only needs one name.

Comment: thanks you for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mail server only has one name and your TLS certificate only needs to have that name. The domains you accept mail for are irrelevant. There is no need to attempt to do this at all.